# Execute code in client-side vs google-cloud-function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am in the situation of having to perform some writes to my database, which have quite a few relationships with different collections and also include file uploads to firebase storage.

At this point was when I asked myself, **should my client take care of the data consistency of my entire application?** Because in reality my client only wants to perform a "simple" operation, although in reality it involves multiple writes to firestore and uploads of files to firebase storage.

My question is: **Should I in this situation use a firestore function or continue executing this code on my client?**

Regardless of the answer, I would also like to know the following:

To run multiple writes on the database, it is advisable to use batch writes or perhaps transactions (depending on the problem). **Is there a way to execute these batch writes or transactions along with file uploads?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a 'right' way to do this. The firestore has a client side library, so you can use it. If you intend to build a REST/GraphQl API you should obviously use cloud functions.

If not, it really depends on the data. If you need to perform a lot of transformations on it, or run some more complex logic to determin what data to read/write you might want to consider using cloud functions over client side because you will get some performance benefits and you will keep your front-end and back-end logic separated. Again, there is no right answer, this is just how I think when choosing between client side and server side to run queries.

Also, there are differences between the client and server APIs. You can check this article: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c

As for your second question, I am not sure what do you mean by file uploads,

Comment: In my case when I talk about uploading files to firebase storage I am referring to uploading images to firebase storage.

Comment: Since both APIs are promise-based, you can chain database operations and storage operations with then statements.If you want to run them more or less in parallel, because both storage and database operations are async calling one api after the other won't mean they get run synchronous, so you can do that.

Comment: Yes, but suppose I add my images to cloud storage and also add the corresponding writes to my firebase firestore.

When both operations have finished uploading images fails, writes to my firebase firestore are successful.

The next step would be to delete the images, otherwise there would be an inconsistency in the data.

And I'm not looking for that. Since what I'm looking for is just an atomic operation.

Comment: The SDK doen't seem to provide any direct link between firestore/realtime database API and storage API. To achieve that behavior you can either uploud your file then write to the databse if the first promise resolves, or you can set up a cloud function that wirtes to the database whenever a file gets uploaded to storage

Comment: But this is still a problem in my opinion because of the atomicity we were talking about earlier. I think that firebase should implement some solution. 
I honestly don't know how to approach this topic in a way that convinces me.